# git: How to prevent fetching tags from upstream repo?

Tags: git, github

I'm new to forking a repo in GitHub. The situation is I have forked my own project, and trying to port the new one into another platform. My original project has many tags corresponding to different versions. But I want to use a different pace (and different version numbers) to update the new project, so I don't want to use any of them in my new project.

The question is that is there any way to prevent commands like `git fetch` from getting all unnecessary tags from upstream repo?

Even if I remove all not-needed tags from my new repo, after next `git fetch` they will come back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git fetch` accepts a `--no-tags` (`-n`) option. I wouldn’t use it, though; if you change the versioning scheme of software, you shouldn’t clobber its existing versions. That’s just confusing.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I'm porting a Chrome extension to another browser, which can share the core codes but uses different API's and other stuffs. Users of the two browsers are from (almost) completely different worlds....Those using the new extension know nothing about the original one, including the version numbers....And I don't expect updating the new one as frequently as the original. So I can't simply jump from say v1.0 to v2.1 all of a sudden. That's why I plan to maintain two different version series separately. Thanks for quick response and kindly suggestion!

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can configure this separately for each remote.

For example, if the `origin` remote points to your new project (with the tags you want) and `upstream` points to the original project (with the tags you don't want), enter the following:

```
git config remote.upstream.tagOpt --no-tags
```

Then, delete the local tags one last time, and `git fetch` will no longer recreate them.

Source: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---no-tags